# Check if two values are either in a dictionary as a key or in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, conditional-statements

I am not sure how to write a logic in the most pythonic way.

I have 2 data types:

`d: Dict[str, Any] = {} l: List[str]: []`
Now I want to write a condition where I check if at least one of the strings is in either the dictionary(as a key) or in list. I am not sure how to do that in the most pythonic way.

I could obviously write:

```
if 'str_1' in d.keys() or 'str_2' id d.keys():
     return True
elif 'str_1' in l or 'str_2' id l:
    return True
```

I am struggling to come up with a way to write this elegantly in a Pythonic way, preferably to have it in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
any(item in coll_ for coll_ in (l, d) for item in (‘str_1’,’str_2’))
```

Answer (score 1):

use a ternary expression like this:

```py
l=["a","c"]
d={'b':'yes'}

key = 'b'
result = True if key in d or key in l else False
```

**Clarification**

The above is the equivalent of:

```py
result = key in d or key in l
```

In a ternary expression you are **not** forced to return boolean.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 yes it is, it's just an example of a ternary expression, based on the question i imagine Donič is learning the language and i prefer to be more expressive to highlight how it works